# Doesn't go-micro support lowercase grpc method name in proto ? #2697

Tags: go, go-micro

I have a proto file defined a rpcc service below :

```
service Greeter {
  rpc handle (Request) returns (Response) {
  }
}
```

in xxx.pb.micro.go, Handle method generated. And I have debug a little, find out go-micro use reflect to get the service name and method, and then register them in somewhere.
but I see in xxx.pb.micro.go, it use lowercase method to gennerate request. This will lead 'unknown service Greeter.handle'

```
func (c *greeterService) Handle(ctx context.Context, in *Request, opts ...client.CallOption) (*Response, error) {
    req := c.c.NewRequest(c.name, "Greeter.handle", in)
    out := new(Response)
    err := c.c.Call(ctx, req, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
```

I mannually change the generated xxx.pb.microgo code from
`req := c.c.NewRequest(c.name, "Greeter.handle", in)` to
`req := c.c.NewRequest(c.name, "Greeter.Handle", in)`
Then it works

So my question is does go-micro only support uppercase name ? Any suggetion will be appreciate